# How to solve the equation $\sin^3x+\sin^3(\frac{2\pi}{3}+x)+\sin^3(\frac{4\pi}{3}+x)+\frac{3}{4}\cos2x=0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Solve the equation $$\sin^3x+\sin^3\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}+x\right)+\sin^3\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}+x\right)+\frac{3}{4}\cos2x=0$$

May I have a hint on how to solve this equation?

Comment: Use $\sin3A$ formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the identity $\sin^3 \theta = \dfrac{3}{4}\sin\theta-\dfrac{1}{4}\sin 3\theta$, we get:

$\sin^3 x + \sin^3(x+\tfrac{2\pi}{3}) + \sin^3(x+\tfrac{4\pi}{3})$

$= \dfrac{3}{4}\left[\sin x + \sin(x+\tfrac{2\pi}{3})+\sin(x+\tfrac{4\pi}{3})\right] - \dfrac{1}{4}\left[\sin 3x + \sin(3x+2\pi) + \sin(3x+4\pi)\right]$

$= \dfrac{3}{4} \cdot 0 - \dfrac{1}{4} \cdot 3\sin3x$

$= -\dfrac{3}{4}\sin 3x$.

Therefore, your equation is equivalant to $-\dfrac{3}{4}\sin 3x + \dfrac{3}{4}\cos 2x = 0$.

Can you take it from here? (The next thing you should do is use one of these [sum-to-product identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities).)

---

Using the identities $\sin\theta = \cos(\tfrac{\pi}{2}-\theta)$ and $\cos A - \cos B = -2\sin\tfrac{A+B}{2}\sin\tfrac{A-B}{2}$, we have:

$\cos 2x - \sin 3x= 0$

$\cos 2x -\cos(\tfrac{\pi}{2}-3x) = 0$

$2\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{5x}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) = 0$

$\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) = 0$ OR $\sin\left(\dfrac{5x}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) = 0$

$\dfrac{x}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{4} = k\pi$ OR $\dfrac{5x}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{4} = k\pi$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

$x = \dfrac{(4k+1)\pi}{2}$ OR $x = \dfrac{(4k+1)\pi}{10}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

It's not hard to see that $x = \dfrac{(4k+1)\pi}{10}$ covers all the values which satisfy $x = \dfrac{(4k+1)\pi}{2}$. So the solution is simply $x = \dfrac{(4k+1)\pi}{10}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $\cos2x=\sin3x$

$1-2\sin^2x+4\sin^3x-3\sinx=0$

$4x^3-2x^2-3x+1=0$

The given solution is $(4k+1)\frac{\pi}{10}$

How to get there

Comment: ^If you try to solve that cubic equation, you get $\sin x \in \{1, \tfrac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{4}, \tfrac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{4}\}$. If you don't know what $\arcsin$ of those values are, then its hard to get that $x = (4k+1)\pi/10$. See my edit for an easier method to arrive at that answer.